# How do I make graphql calls in series? react-apollo

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

I am composing 2 queries in a `hoc` with `react-apollo`.  Here is my code:

```
let queries = compose(
  graphql(gql`
    query getUnitSubcategories($input: UnitSubcategorySearchInput) {
      allUnitSubcategories(input:$input) {
        edges {
          node {
            unitSubcategoryId
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `, {
    name: 'subcategories',
    options: {
      variables: {
        input: {
          activeFlag: true,
        }
      }
    }
  }),
  graphql(gql`
    query getFinancialTransactions($input: FinancialTransactionLineSearchInput) {
      allFinancialTransactionLines(input: $input) {
        pageInfo {
          total
        }
        edges {
          node {
            financialTransaction {
              financialTransactionId
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `, {
    name: 'financialTransactions',
    options: {
      variables: {
        input: {
          unitSubcategories: [
            ....
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  })
);
```

You can see that I am getting the `unitSubcategories` in the first query and they need to be passed to the second query.  So I don't want to kick off the second query until I have a result from my first query.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: i havent used either apollo or react-apollo but from your code since `graphql` returns a promise i would think that you can do `compose(graphql(request1 stuff).then(result => { return graphql(request 2 stuff with result data) }))`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `skip` config. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-skip

In your example, you might want to define the `skip` config in the second query something like this:

```
{
  name: 'financialTransactions',
  skip: ({ unitSubcategories }) => !unitSubcategories,
  options: ({ unitSubcategories }) => ({
    variables: {
      input: {
        unitSubcategories
      }
    }
  })
}
```

where you only want the second query to run after you've received the result from the first query. And then use `options` as a function so you can compute them from `props`.